# ImageButton and Preferences

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

How can I create an `ImageButton` (musicButton) that control setting music on or off ?

I have `GamePrefs class` that has these 2 methods

```
public static void setBoolean(String name, boolean val) {
    prefs.setBoolean(name, val);
    prefs.flush();
}

public static boolean getBoolean(String name) {
    return prefs.getBoolean(name);
}
```

I have two images for the `musicButton`

```
Texture t1 = new Texture("music");
Texture t2 = new Texture("music_off");
TextureRegion tr1 = new TextureRegion(t1);
TextureRegion tr2 = new TextureRegion(t2);
```

I know I need to make an `ImageButtonStyle` but I have many fields `imageUp`, `imageDown`, `checked`, `checkedOver`... I don't know which two I should use

and I need it to respond to touch and changing current music setting to on or off

something like this :

`GamePrefs.setBoolean("music", false)` or `GamePrefs.setBoolean("music", true)`

and I will use `getBoolean()` to play music or not

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating such kind of buttons I used `ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle` with `up` and `checked` attributes:

```
public Button getMusicButton() {
    final Button button = new ImageButton(getMusicButtonStyle());
    button.setChecked(Prefs.isMusicOn());
    button.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            MusicHandler.getInstance().toggleMusic();
        }
    });
    return button;
}

private ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle getMusicButtonStyle() {
    ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle style = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
    style.up = musicOffDrawable;
    style.checked = musicOnDrawable;
    return style;
}
```

For music and sounds I have `MusicHandler` class with this method:

```
public void toggleMusic() {
    Prefs.toggleMusic();
    if (!Prefs.isMusicOn()) {
        music.stop();
    } else {
        music.play();
    }
}
```

And finally in `Prefs` class there are:

```
public static boolean isMusicOn() {
    return pref.getBoolean(MUSIC_ON);
}

public static void toggleMusic() {
    pref.putBoolean("music_on", !isMusicOn());
    pref.flush();
}
```